# Importing data into a Mongodb schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Node.js and Express.js. I am working a Voting App to enhance my skills. The following is the data schema I created.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const register = mongoose.Schema;

const Voter = new register({ 
    firstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    lastName:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },

    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },

    vote:{
        type:Number
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Voter',Voter)
```

Most of the examples/practice problems I encountered require the user to complete the data input on ONE page. **But I am thinking if there is a way to have 3 keys filled using one page, and 1 other key filled using another page.**

My preliminary design is to have the user filled in their names and email in the **registration page** and save them to the database, and once that is completed the user will be directed to **voting page** to click vote button and have that input saved to the database. In total 4 entries are saved in one Schema.

I have had the registration page constructed.

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const Voter = require('../models/voter');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('cand/profiles')
})

router.get('/loggedin',async (req,res)=>{
    res.render('cand/index')
})

router.post('/loggedin',async (req,res)=>{
    const register = new Voter({
        firstName:req.body.first_Name,
        lastName:req.body.last_Name,
        email:req.body.email,
    })

    if (req.body.first_Name!==''||req.body.last_Name!==''||req.body.email!==''){
        var newVoter = await register.save()
        //res.send('Hello')
        res.render('cand/index',{
            voterFirstName:newVoter.firstName,
            voterLastName:newVoter.lastName,
            voterEmail:newVoter.email
        })
        console.log(newVoter)

    }else{
        res.redirect('/')
    }

})

module.exports=router
```

How am I supposed to deliver those filled key to the **voting page**?

Comment: What frontend framework you using?

Comment: no framework, just HTML and CSS, starting from the basic stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the example below. The **action = "/login"** will redirect to login path.

```
<div class="form">
<form action="/login" method = "post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" required/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

The js code which will be used to redirect to a specific route

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect : '/home', 
    failureRedirect : '/login', 
    failureFlash : true
}));

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
        response.render('pages/home');
});
```

For displaying data from mongoose. Try the follow way.

```
<div id = "profile">
<h3>My Profile Info:</h3>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type = "text" value = "<%= user.user.username %>" />
       </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Here username is fetched from mongodb and send to html in the following way:

```
app.get('/profile', auth, function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/profile', {
        user : request.user
    });
})
```

Comment: Your method looks great, and it could be a good learning material for ID verification (I am not there yet). I will approve your answer tho. Thanks, I kind of figured out the solution myself. I will post it in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

After a hard fight, I finally came up with a solution that can solve the problem I originally raised. So what I did was that **having the pages for user inputs created on one routes.js file. And rendering these pages separately with multiple HTTP request methods.** So the pages rendered on different path will be able to let the user enter different info.

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const Voter = require('../models/voter');
const Ballot = require('../models/ballot')

//ignore the registration for now
var newVoter=''

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('cand/profiles')
})

router.get('/loggedin',async (req,res)=>{
    res.render('cand/index')
})

router.post('/loggedin',async (req,res)=>{
    const register = new Voter({
        firstName:req.body.first_Name,
        lastName:req.body.last_Name,
        email:req.body.email,
    })

    if (req.body.first_Name!==''||req.body.last_Name!==''||req.body.email!==''){
        newVoter = await register.save()

        res.render('cand/index',{
            voterFirstName:newVoter.firstName,
            voterLastName:newVoter.lastName,
            voterEmail:newVoter.email
        })

    }else{
        res.redirect('/')
    }

})
router.get('/loggedin/testing',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(newBallot)
})

//testing
router.post('/loggedin/testing',async (req,res)=>{
    //res.send(newVoter)
    const ballot_info = new Ballot({
        ballotFirstName:newVoter.firstName,
        ballotLastName:newVoter.lastName,
        voteCasted:req.body.ballot
    })

    newBallot = await ballot_info.save()
    res.send(newBallot)
})

module.exports=router
```

But as you can see here, **TWO Schemas are created**. The rationale for that is the 1st page user inputs are stored the 1st Schema. For first 3 keys in the 2nd schema, they were just filled with duplicated info from 1st Schema; the 4th key in the 2nd schema is for the user input acquired from the 2nd page. 
It is a bit wordy I know. :(